# Spring @Transactional Service. What happens if it calls another @Transactional Service?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-transactions

Using Spring, I am reaching the following scenario.

I have a service that has to be `@Transactional` because it calls several DAOs. But it also calls other services that are already `@Transactional`.

Somehow, I will be calling nested `@Transactional` services.

Will Spring manage well?

Comment: Spring will group them all under the same transaction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Transactional` without any explicit parameters uses `propagation = REQUIRED`. This means:

- If there is no transaction in the current thread, a new transaction will be created
- If there is a transaction, it will be used

The 2nd service (the nested one) annotated with `@Transactional` will be executed in the same transaction as the 1st one (the outer one). You don't need to do anything.

In some cases if you want to explicitly separate the nested call from the outer one you can use `propagation = REQUIRES_NEW`.