# Spring @Transactional method with save() command

Tags: spring, transactions, save

please can somebody help me?

I have experience with JPA, but not so with Spring, that hides many aspects, that are visible in JPA (for example Hibernate implementation).

Often I was used to work in JPA in this mode (one global transaction) - I will try to explain on saving header (method_A) and its items (method_B) - with result in posting all or nothing. I would like to reach this effect via Spring persistence. I know, that method with @Transactional annotation gets the session from outside, if this exists. My problem is, that I think, that the nested implemented save() method of default Spring repository interface (CrudRepository for example) will open its own transaction anyway - and this is, what I don't want - simply I need to force this save() method to get it from outside. And so I am not sure, if only @Transactional annotation is enough to force this behavior.

### This is my JPA code, that works properly in Hibernate:

```
root_method() {
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
  
  method_A(session);

tx.commit();
}

method_A(Session session) { 
  Header header = new Header();
  session.save(header);

  for (Item item : getJustAllocatedItems()) {
    item.setHeader(header);
    method_B(session, item);
  }
}

method_B(Session session, Item item) {
  session.save(item);
}
```

I am sorry, that this is not pure Java, but for explanation purposes I hope it is enough. I will try to mirror Spring code in brute form:

```
@Transactional
root_method() {
  // ... root_method should make overal transaction frame on background (I suppose, that root_method is not called from another method with @Transactional ann.)

  method_A();
}

@Transactional
method_A() { 
  Header header = new Header();
  headerRepository.save(header);

  for (Item item : getJustAllocatedItems()) {
    item.setHeader(header);
    method_B(item);
  }
}

@Transactional
method_B(Item item) {
  itemRepository.save(item);
}
```

... so I do not think, that save() methods of repositories (in both A and B method) will receive and use transaction from outside - am I right? - and if it is so, please can somebody interpret my JPA code from first part to appropriate Spring representation. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

If you call repository method without transaction, then repository
will create transaction:

```
Creating new transaction with name [org...SimpleJpaRepository.save]
Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager
```

If you use transactional annotation (Note that it should be in separate service), then save will [reuse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58207893/878241) transaction:

```
Creating new transaction with name [com...HeaderService.createHeader]
Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager
```

Please note, mathods, annotated with @Transactional, should be in different classes (or you should autowire current class using setter). Then Spring will be able to use proxy. Spring wraps service with @Transactional annoaions into proxy.

Enable jpa logging:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.orm.jpa=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.transaction=DEBUG
```

This is example implementation of your classes hierarcy:

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class HeaderService {
    HeaderRepository headerRepository;
    ItemService itemService;

    @Transactional
    public void methodA() {
        Header header = new Header();
        headerRepository.save(header);
        for (Item item : getJustAllocatedItems()) {
            item.setHeader(header);
            itemService.methodB(item);
        }
    }
}

@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ItemService {
    ItemRepository itemRepository;
    @Transactional
    void methodB(item) {
        itemRepository.save(item);
    }
}

public interface HeaderRepository extends CrudRepository<Header, Long> { }
public interface ItemRepository extends CrudRepository<Item, Long> { }
```

Comment: Jevgenij thank you so much - you can't imagine, how your answer helped me. I tried and tested code according to your instructions and things became functional. You are good man and surely experienced developer. Thank you one more time and I wish if there could by more so helpful people as you are in this world. Good luck.